# How to interpret when the normal equation is undefined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, orthogonality, tangent-line

**Function $f(x)$ is given as $f(x) = x + \dfrac{1}{x}$**. I'm asked to find the line of a tangent and normal at $x = 1$.

I'm able to obtain the gradient, *m*, of the function at $ x = 1$. Since the first derivative of the $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2}$, then

$$m_t = f'(1) = 0.$$

Consequently, the equation of the tangent line is:

$$y-2 = m_t (x - 1) \implies y = 2$$

But, using the properity that $m_{n} \times m_{t} = -1 $, we get that the equation of a normal line is undefined since
$$m_{n} = -\dfrac{1}{0}.$$

My question here is, is the correct answer to say that the *equation of the normal* is not defined or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This means Eq. of tangent is $y=2$ and the normal is $y-2=m_n(x-1) \implies 
(x-1)=\frac{y-2}{m_n}=0$. Hence the equation of required normal  is $x=1$.